Align widgets vertically across multiple colums in flutter
Let's say I have column 1 with widgets A, B and C and column 2 with widgets D and E. Column 1 and 2 are in a Row. How do I align A with D and C with E vertically.
    Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          // Column 1
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              WidgetA(), // Widget A
              WidgetB(), // Widget B
              WidgetC(), // Widget C
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20), // Add some space between columns
          // Column 2
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              WidgetD(), // Widget D
              SizedBox(height: 40), // Add spacing to align D with A
              WidgetE(), // Widget E
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),

Widgets D and E have variable sizes based upon their content. There are 'Text' widget and can be one or more lines tall.

Have you tried a table widget instead?

Please share image that you want to create.

What if you make a column with three rows? If I got the question correct, this should work:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Alignment test"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text("Widget A"),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                Container(
                  child: Text("Widget D has very long text\nwith multiple lines"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                child: Container(
                  child: Text("Widget B"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text("Widget C"),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                Container(
                  child: Text("Widget E has very long text as well\nwith multiple lines\nand another one"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

You should be able to replace my Containers with Text by your WidgetA() etc. Hope this helps!
